# PgSearch 1.0.0 throws ModelNotMultisearchable error when trying to rebuild from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, pg-search

I've got an app with 4 different models which are multisearchable, however they were originally set up with a pg_search_scope; ie:

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  # multisearchable :against => [:title, :description]

  pg_search_scope :search_text,
    :against => [:title, :description],
    :using => {
               :tsearch => {:prefix => true}
              }
```

As you can see at one point I tried setting this up the multiserachable way.

Of late there are items we know should be returning that are NOT in the search results, and I thought I'd have to rebuild the pg_search_documents; however that's throwing an error:

```
irb(main):004:0> PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Show)
PgSearch::Multisearch::ModelNotMultisearchable: PgSearch::Multisearch::ModelNotMultisearchable
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pg_search-0.7.3/lib/pg_search/multisearch/rebuilder.rb:6:in `initialize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pg_search-0.7.3/lib/pg_search/multisearch.rb:10:in `new'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pg_search-0.7.3/lib/pg_search/multisearch.rb:10:in `block in rebuild'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pg_search-0.7.3/lib/pg_search/multisearch.rb:8:in `rebuild'
    from (irb):4
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0>
```

I thought that it might be because of the setup as a pg_search_scope, so I set one class as above with the multisearch:multisearchable :against => [:title, :description] -- but even then I get rebuild problems.

I tried the manual way of deleting from the pg_search table and rebuilding but even THAT's throwing an error:

```
2.1.0 :010 > Show.find_each{ |record| record.update_pg_search_document }
  Show Load (4.8ms)  SELECT "shows".* FROM "shows" ORDER BY "shows"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_pg_search_document' for #<Show:0x007fd945a92358>
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/acts_as_follower-0.2.1/lib/acts_as_follower/followable.rb:54:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):10:in `block in irb_binding'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:26:in `each'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:26:in `block in find_each'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:75:in `find_in_batches'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:70:in `find_in_batches'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:25:in `find_each'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `find_each'
    from (irb):10
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error while trying to rebuild (for the first time, installing) via the Rails command line with `PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Professor)`. What's worked for me is instead rebuilding from the command line using [the alternative approach](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#rebuilding-search-documents-for-a-given-class) recommended on the Github:

`rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Professor]`

This seems to work for me -- it doesn't throw an error, and when I go to the Rails console after and run `PgSearch.multisearch("query")` it's returning a result, whereas before it was returning an error.

I know this isn't a fix, but it's a solution to the immediate problem. I hope it helps -- posting an issue on their Github might lead to a fuller fix.

Comment: Sadly not for me - I'm getting Show is not multisearchable. See PgSearch::ClassMethods#multisearchable.

Comment: So you're trying `PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Show)`, but the model you've put `include PgSearch` and `multisearchable :against => [:title, :description]` in is `Episode` -- seems like you're trying to rebuild on the wrong model? Try putting those two lines (against changed, of course) in your Show model and trying again.